# Meaning of Isomorphism

Tags: proof-writing

In Hilton's *A Course in Homological Algebra* Page 21. $A$ is a ring with unit which is not necessarily commutative. Here is Propsition 3.4:

Prop3.4: Let $B$ be an $A$-module and $\{A_{j}\}_{j\in J}$ be a family of $A$-modules. Then there is an isomorphism
$$ \eta: \operatorname{Hom}_{A}(\oplus_{j\in J}A_{j},B)\rightarrow\prod_{j\in J}\operatorname{Hom}_{A}(A_{j},B).
$$

I am just confused what the isomorphism actually
means, since we can only prove it's a group isomorphism and both **may not have a module structure**. Is the author's writings
are not quite rigorous or the abbreviation is reasonable?

Comment: Why "may not have a module structure"?

Comment: Suppose $A_{i},A_{j}$ denotes A-module. Because the ring A may not be commutative, we can't give $Hom_{A}(A_{i},A_{j})$ a standard  A-module structure $\lambda\psi(a):=\psi(\lambda(a))$ just directly checking the module conditions.

Comment: To be precise, it should be an isomorphism of $\mathbb Z$-modules. You're right!

Comment: If either $B$ or all the $A_i$s are bimodules, then the $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathfrak{M}_A}$ (or in ${}_A\mathfrak{M}$) have a natural $A$-module structure and you have an isomorphism of $A$-modules.  Otherwise, you only have a $\mathbb{Z}$-module isomorphism.

Comment: I think I can understand it now! Thank you.

Comment: isomorphism of abelian groups may be?